# Has a food taster ever thwarted an assassination attempt?

Tags: food, assassination

Important people have been known to employ [food tasters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_taster) to avoid assassination by poisoning.  The linked Wikipedia article mentions that Claudius, Adolf Hitler, Barack Obama, and Vladimir Putin all used food tasters.

Has there ever been an actual assassination attempt that was successfully thwarted by a food taster's reaction?  That is, was there any historical figure who chose not to eat food that was prepared for them because their food taster tried it first and ended up sick or dead?  If so, what are the earliest and most recent documented cases?

I acknowledge that food tasters may deter assassination attempts; I'm specifically asking about assassination attempts that were thwarted only after the food taster ingested the food.

Comment: It is possible that food taster's work through deterrence; that the presence of a food taster deters people from attempting assassination through poison.  It is possible that uncountable assassination plots have been deterred, but none have been detected.  Reminds me of the old joke about the guy selling "Tiger protection charms" in New York.  A skeptic challenged, "There are no tigers in New York!", and the salesman replied, "These charms work; I need to raise the price!"

Comment: @MCW: That's true, and it's also why I'm specifically asking about assassination attempts that were thwarted only after the food taster ingested the food.

Comment: So the question devolves to, "Has anyone attempted to poison someone who was effectively defended against poison?"?

Comment: @MCW More like, "Has any food taster been poisoned in the line of duty?"

Comment: Which is the same as asking, "are there any really stupid assassins?  Assassins who would choose a technique that they know the target has already defended."  Nobody _wants_ to poison someone; poison is a means to the end.

Answer (score 2):

In general, awareness of the taster is likely to preclude the planning of an assassination in which a person would be poisoned through food.

One example of a food taster ‘doing his job’ may be seen in the story of Mark Antony and Cleopatra. Although the two are arguably one of ancient history’s best-known lovers, it looks like they seemed to have distrusted each other. According to Pliny the Elder in his Natural History, during the time leading up to the fateful Battle of Actium in 31 BC, Mark Antony  distrusted Cleopatra and was worried that she would poison him when she no longer had any use for him,and because of thathe had a food taster on hand all the time.

Pliny says that Cleopatra found this amusing, and decided to entertain herself at his expense. Therefore, at a banquet, she wore a circlet of flowers, of which their extremities were dipped in poison, on her head. As the party progresses, Cleopatra challenged Mark to swallow the flowers by mixing them with wine. Antony could not refuse the challenge, and nearly drank the poisoned wine when the queen herself stopped him. She then summoned **his** food taster, who, needless to say, dropped dead after drinking the wine. Thus, Cleopatra demonstrated to Mark Antony that the best precaution he had against being poisoned was to trust her. And that she was ruthless for letting a taster die knowing it was poisonous. [A Deadly Bite: The Plight of the Ancient Food Taster](https://www.ancient-origins.net/history-famous-people/deadly-bite-plight-ancient-food-taster-009193)

Comment: So, it wasn't the food taster who foiled the attempt, _but Cleo herself?_

Comment: Technically so.

Comment: I've often thought that a food taster with an undetected allergy could be harmed by a food leading to an accusation of poisoning when there was no such intent. Shellfish, coeliac etc

Comment: @bigbadmouse: I've seen the claim that the food-taster was often the chef - which if so would in most cases avert such an occurrence.